# Why Kaspersky try to host more than one Shadow Roots?

Tags: javascript, dom

When users use **Kaspersky** antivirus on my web page, they get error:

> Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts
>   a shadow root is deprecated. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more
>   details.

So my question is why kaspersky tries to add another shadow root on the page? This error crashes all the page.
Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: Don't think it's the antivirus.But it's possible for some web-rep extension budled with it to modify DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was kaspersky plugin for browser and Adblock, that blocked some content (Css class - "adman" was enterpreted as advertisement)